# Video upload to DB using jquery ajax along with form datas

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file

This is the code for the script part. Here I have done email validation and if that is true then run the script. I need to upload a video file to the database along with this form of data.someone, please help to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance

```js
<script>
    function sendContact() {
        var valid;
        valid = validateContact();
        if (valid) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "Submit.php",
                data: 'FirstName=' + $("#FirstName").val() + '&LastName=' + $("#LastName").val() + '&EmailId=' + $("#EmailId").val() + '&Link1=' + $("#Link").val() + '&file1=' + $("#file").val() + '&CheckBox1=' + $("#CheckBox1").val() + '&CheckBox2=' + $("#CheckBox2").val() + '&VideoText=' + $("#VideoText").val() + '&Text=' + $("#Text").val(),+ '&captcha=' + $("#captcha").val(),
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#mail-status").html(data);
                },
                error: function () { }
            });
        }
    }

    function validateContact() {
        var valid = true;
        $("#EmailId-info").html("");
        $("#CEmailId-info").html("");
        var email = $("#EmailId").val();
        var confemail = $("#CEmailId").val();
        if (email != confemail) {
            $("#CEmailId-info").html("(Email not matching!)");

            valid = false;
        }
        if (!$("#EmailId").val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)) {
            $("#EmailId-info").html("(invalid)");

            valid = false;
        }

        if (!$("#CEmailId").val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)) {
            $("#CEmailId-info").html("(invalid)");

            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: video is upload by `<input type=file>?`

Comment: <form id="fupForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <input type="text" name="Link" id="Link" class="form-control"> </div>  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="form-control" />
                                                            </div>
         </div>
       <button type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit"  onClick="sendContact()" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #333;">Submit</button></form>

Comment: this is my form html data part.

Comment: Actually what i want to do is to upload video file to database along with other form values after checking whether  email is matching with confirmation email id.